# Question about let syntax in type systems

Tags: type-theory, type-checking, type-inference

I'm on the Wikipedia page for Hindley-Milner type systems, on the section about "let polymorphism": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Let-polymorphism

I'm a bit confused on this sentence:

> Ideally, this would be allowed with any use of a bound variable

What does that mean exactly? I'm not following the syntax in this section.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell that section is just poorly written. What you should get out of it is that HM can only generalize `let` bound functions, and that this change (or some change) is necessary because type inference (and type checking) are undecidable in the polymorphic lambda calculus. If you've understood that, I wouldn't put any more effort into deciphering what the author of that section intended.